# Cant build NextJS React on AWS Amplify - "Please enable output standalone on your next.config.js file..."

Tags: reactjs, next.js, aws-amplify

I have a react app I made with NextJS that I'm trying to deploy to AWS Amplify. I'm deploying directly from my github. I'm using all default settings in my Amplify service.

I keep getting this error at build:

> /output/src874801190/src/symbiote-react/dist/standalone. Please enable output standalone on your next.config.js file or set NEXT_PRIVATE_STANDALONE=true. https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing#automatically-copying-traced-files

As you can see my output IS set to 'standalone'.
I've even set 'NEXT_PRIVATE_STANDALONE' environmental variable in Amplify to True, and I still get this error. I'm completely out of ideas here. Can't even find anything on google. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

And yes, my app works fine on my local machine under dev and production mode. Everything is up-to-date.

**next.config.js**

```
/**
 * @type {import('next').NextConfig}
 */
const nextConfig = {
  output: 'standalone',
  //assetPrefix: '/static',
  // Optional: Add a trailing slash to all paths `/about` -> `/about/`
  // trailingSlash: true,
  // Optional: Change the output directory `out` -> `dist`
  // distDir: 'dist',

  async rewrites() {
        return [
            {
                source: '/symbiote',
                destination: '/',
            },
        ];
    },
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "litbot_react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "20.1.0",
    "@types/react": "18.2.6",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.4",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "eslint": "8.40.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.1",
    "gpt-3-encoder": "^1.1.4",
    "gpt-token-utils": "^1.2.0",
    "gpt3-tokenizer": "^1.1.5",
    "next": "^13.4.5",
    "postcss": "8.4.23",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-modal": "^3.16.1",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.2",
    "tiktoken": "^1.0.7",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react-modal": "^3.16.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  }
}
```